# Standard Individual and Standard Company

Tags: iphone

My question is:

I know the difference between a Standard Individual program and a Standard Company Program, that with the individual program only one developer can develop an application with this account, but in the real life, with a Standard individual Program, there are many developers who can works with this count. my question is what is the difference between both programs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A standard company account allows teams members to use their own separate ADC logins, which means the team leader doesn't have to give out their password.  An individual account only allows one login account.